# How to encode json in php like this

Tags: php

```
{
  "status": "1",
  "error": "",
  "result": {
    "payment": {
      "issue_date": "2017-01-18",
      "payment_status": "Not Paid",
      "name": "GYM Master - GYM Management System",
      "address": "address",

    },
    "receiver": {
      "first_name": "Gauang",
      "last_name": "vyas",
      "address": "ldrp",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, what are you starting with? And have you tried anything? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has native function for encoding/decoding JSON

```
json_encode
json_decode
```

It accepts arrays and objects for your convienence.

Example:

```
$data = array(
   'status' => 1,
   'result' => array(
      'example' => 'example...'
   )
)

json_encode($data)
```

That will result in:

```
{
   "status":1,
   "result":{
      "example":"example..."
   }
}
```